# Is compile-time info available at run-time?

Tags: ios, runtime, compile-time

In iOS, a nice-to-have would be an about page that has the 'release date' of the app... which I'd rather not have to update by hand.  Is there some way to glean the date the app was compiled?  Preprocessor, or inspecting the app, or something I can't think of?

Comment: Oh wow... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917686/compile-date-and-time  *runs off and tests*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question feels dirty, but hey, it's the answer:

```
NSString *compiled = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__DATE__];
```